# Execution failed for task ':simple_edge_detection:externalNativeBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, edge-detection

i am using simple_edge_detection library from here :

https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/implementing-edge-detection-in-flutter/2020/1509/

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
include_directories(../include)
add_library(lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java4.so)
set(EDGE_DETECTION_DIR "../ios/Classes")
set(SOURCES
    ${EDGE_DETECTION_DIR}/native_edge_detection.cpp
    ${EDGE_DETECTION_DIR}/edge_detector.cpp
    ${EDGE_DETECTION_DIR}/image_processor.cpp
)
add_library(native_edge_detection SHARED ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(native_edge_detection lib_opencv)
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
  //  flavorDimensions "default"

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "dev.flutterclutter.simple_edge_detection_example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags '-frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11'
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"

            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "D:/Flutter Projects/flutter-simple-edge-detection/example/android/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

but m getting this error :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> Execution failed for task ':simple_edge_detection:externalNativeBuildDebug'.

> Build command failed.
> Error while executing process C:\Users\Andorid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\Flutter Projects\flutter-simple-edge-detection\android.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a --target native_edge_detection}

> ninja: error: '../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java4.so', needed by 'D:/Flutter Projects/flutter-simple-edge-detection/example/build/simple_edge_detection/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative_edge_detection.so', missing and no known rule to make it

Comment: Have you ever managed to fix this issue?